# What is the proper syntax in MySQL for constructing multiples JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I am new to SQL and trying to construct a join for 6 tables together. Here is my example code:

```
SELECT cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID, cr.CONSUMER_ID, cr.ACTION_LOG_ID, nc.CONSUMER_ID, cal.CONSUMER_ID, cal.TIPS_AMOUNT, cal.LAST_MOD_TIME, cirm.CONSUMER_RATING, ces.EXPERT_SCORE, cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID, scs.SIMILARITY
FROM COMMUNICATION_RELVANCE AS cr
JOIN network_communications AS nc
ON cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID=nc.COMMUNICATIONS_ID
JOIN consumer_action_log AS cal
ON cr.ACTION_LOG_ID=cal.ACTION_LOG_ID
JOIN communication_interest_mapping AS cim
ON cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID=cim.COMMUNICATIONS_ID
JOIN consumer_interest_rating_mapping AS cirm
ON cr.CONSUMER_ID=cirm.CONSUMER_ID
    AND cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID=cirm.CONSUMER_INTEREST_ID
JOIN consumer_expert_score AS ces
ON nc.CONSUMER_ID=ces.CONSUMER_ID
    AND cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID=CONSUMER_EXPERT_ID
JOIN survey_customer_similarity AS scs
ON nc.CONSUMER_ID=scs.CONSUMER_ID
    AND cal.CONSUMER_ID=scs.CONSUMER_ID;
```

Before I start debugging, I want to make sure there are not any wholesale problems in my code my syntax.

Comment: Execute the query. Then you will see if there are any syntax errors. That's what I would do if I wanted to check your query for syntax errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks fine to me. Try running it to see if there are any errors.

A couple of points:

- You don't have a WHERE clause so it will return all rows. Is that intentional?
- You misspelled the name of one of your tables: `COMMUNICATION_RELVANCE`. You probably should fix that before your write too much more code. I know it sounds pedantic but it's because fixing it now during initial development is probably quite easy to do. If you leave it too long people will write code that relies on the misspelling and it might end up being too difficult/expensive to change the name and update all the existing code. Then you'll be stuck with it and it will annoy everyone who has to maintain your code for years to come.

Comment: +1: Good advice, regarding fixing spelling errors early on. I have to deal with it currently on a project where it is misspelled in a stored proc, but I can't change it o_O

Answer (score 0):

All lines look fine, except you probably want to add an alias to this line against `CONSUMER_EXPERT_ID` to be "proper"

```
AND cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID=CONSUMER_EXPERT_ID
```